# objective c: EXC_BAD_ADDRESS

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access

can anyone tell me why this results in a EXC_BAD_ADDRESS error?

```
int startIndex = NSRangeFromString(current).location + NSRangeFromString(current).length;
NSLog(@"%d", NSRangeFromString(current).location + NSRangeFromString(current).length);
NSLog(@"%@", startIndex);
```

anything referencing startIndex results in the error

the second line prints 6, so startIndex should print 6?

Comment: You might need to post more code so we can get a sense of how your variables are declared, especially `startIndex` and `current`. What is `startIndex`'s class?

Comment: startIndex is just a primitive int.

Answer (score 4):

If startIndex is an int of float then you need to use

`NSLog(@"%d", startIndex);` or `NSLog(@"%f", startIndex);`

The `%@` is only for objects